# Outdoor definition

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I have a controversy with my husband about 'outdoor' term. I think that outdoor mostly means smth associated with sport, tourism or different activities. My husband supposes that this term means any action outside buildings. He consider wedding or work on streets as outdoor either.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Elina.  What dictionaries have you consulted?  What do they say that you cannot understand?

Comment: I wouldn't hold a wedding outdoors; it always rains.

Comment: @deadrat In most films it doesn't, except in "About Time".

Comment: Many English terms have significant nuances, but "outdoor" does not.  It applies to any activity which is not within the confines of a building or habitable structure.  In certain contexts, however, there may be connotations:  If someone asks if you participate in any "outdoor activities", eg, they're basically asking if you participate in sports or games outside, or possibly such activities as gardening.

Comment: You might be thinking about "outdoors" rather than "outdoor". Though they have basically the same meaning, outdoors has more of the connotations that you're thinking of. An "outdoor" activity would be one that happens outside of a building, but an "outdoors" activity would be more likely to imply that it's a sporting or wilderness activity. We talk about "the great outdoors" when referring to activities like camping, hiking, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

Much as I hate to interfere with a marriage in conflict, I must side with your husband on this matter. The word "outdoor" can be used to indicate any object or activity that takes place or exists outside of a building. For example, an "outdoor shower" is simply a shower that is outside of a building, such as you might find at a swimming pool or as an ad-hoc convenience in a disaster-relief situation.